# how to make geth light node connect to local full node

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients

In my computer i have 1 full node, my full node is running using: `geth --syncmode full --ws --wsport 8546`. Is there anyway to create a light node to connect to that full node on the same local network manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

On your full node, run the command `admin.nodeInfo.enode`, you will get an output like this:

```
"enode://0a8b31379d8b583784d5d500a5c77623518817e4fa166bbe4a3054dc796e165f9cf15ff0f96s2af47d7705cc72c354494f8b0e0ab167b1c7a52f19a74a174905@[::]:30303"
```

This is your node's [enode](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/enode-url-format). Replace the `[::]` part with the computer's IP, like so:

```
"enode://0a8b ... 4905@192.168.88.111:30303"
```

Now run your light node with `geth --syncmode light`, and then run `admin.addPeer(<enode>)` in the console:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://0a8b ... 4905@192.168.88.111:30303")
```